# How to use session's property in java application

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, spring-security, session-variables

I have enabled security for my application, and these protected resources cannot be accessed unless the user is logged in.

However, I need to run multiple tests inside my java application. I wonder whether it is possible to login to my application from login-page (**browser**), use its session-id, and gain the authenticated object for my tests (**java application**)?

If it helps, I am using spring security.

*I am looking for the general idea, if it takes time to explain how to do it.*

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security's [Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) has a handle on the current user's principal and authorized roles.  It can be accessed using:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

Spring's [RequestAttributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestAttributes.html) has a handle on the current session id.  It can be accessed using:

```
RequestAttributes attributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
String sessionId = attributes.getSessionId();
```

This works provided the [RequestContextFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html) has been configured in web.xml.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, you should know that the TEST-APPLICATION is running standalone. So it may neither know about nor have access to `SecurityContextHolder`. Isn't there a way, to use a `session-id` , retrieve it and use its contents?